# Can I search Radare's help system?

Tags: radare2, documentation

Radare2 seems to have thousands of commands. Is there a way to search all of those commands?

Like let's say I want to find all commands that had `rot` (for [`rot13`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13)), is there a method to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to find a command with searching over all help texts like this:

```
?*
```

And to filter the result simply add this:

```
?*~keyword
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `?*~...` to do interactive search in all help commands:

[image]

Comment: Can you validate the answer then?

Comment: @EvanCarroll this is not **exactly** what defragger wrote as the 3 dots are not a placeholder for a keyword, if you enter this command as is, you can **do interactive search in all help commands**

Comment: Wow that is really cool. Thanks for the clarification I change my downvote to an upvote.

Comment: I wonder, is it possible to put it there by default? I mean, anytime i type any single command, I'd like these suggestions to pop up and start scrolling.